# Cocoa: Update views outside NSWindow's content view during live window resizing?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a standard `NSWindow` with a toolbar. One of the toolbar's items is a custom view -- specifically, an `NSTextField`. (More specifically, it's a timer app -- the timer's controls as well as the digital display are all within the toolbar, with other stuff in the window's content area. The `NSTextField` is the digital display.)

Ordinarily, I just update the timer every second by changing the '`stringValue`' property of the `NSTextField`, which causes it to update itself. But during a live window resize, even though the code that updates the '`stringValue`' property is running (which I have verified with `NSLog`), the `NSTextField` doesn't draw itself again until the window resizing is done. Meanwhile, the stuff inside the content area is updating itself just fine.

I've tried all the ways I know to tell the `NSTextField` to draw itself, but it just refuses to happen until the live resize is done. Any ideas? Obviously it must be possible somehow, as the toolbar gets resized along with the rest of the window -- so you'd think it would be possible to force it to redraw one or more of its `subviews` as it is moving them around. I'm assuming I can hack this together by `subclassing` *something*, but my Cocoa-fu is not yet strong enough to figure out the easiest/most proper way to do so.

Thanks in advance...

EDIT: I kind of figured out a solution -- it's not great but it mostly works for now. It's in my comments below.

Comment: You don't mention how your trigger your timer.  Have you tried putting the code in a background thread?

Comment: Try setup a delegate when NSWindow resize and tell the `NSTextField` to redraw itself with `setNeedsDisplay:` or something else. If that doesn't work then yeah it's probably a thread problem.

Comment: @trojanfoe (Just repeating my previous comment in case you wanted the follow-up, as I forgot to tag you the first time... sorry, new to Stack Overflow.) The timer is set to fire every second. Which it does even during window resizing. The problem is that when I update the view content in response to the timer, the changes don't actually get drawn until the live resizing is done. Am hoping to avoid dealing with extra threads if possible... if that's the only solution, I'll just deal with the lack of updating during resizing, which is annoying but not a dealbreaker.

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer Thanks, I have some new info now. I tried calling `setNeedsDisplay:` and also calling `drawRect:` directly -- both of which "worked" in the sense that they got executed (I checked with `NSLog` and the debugger), but seemingly they aren't drawing anything. It looks like both the other views (which DO update) and the `NSTextField` in the toolbar (which doesn't) are running their `drawRect:` on the main app thread, so I'm less inclined to suspect threading problems now. Think I figured something out though -- see next comment.

Comment: Actually, I lied -- I thought I'd figured out a solution but it turns out I just got lucky in my earlier testing and it doesn't actually work consistently, so I deleted those comments. Still working on a REAL solution...

Comment: (1/3) OK! I have finally more or less figured it out. It's kind of an ugly kludge, but it's good enough for now. The first thing I worked out is that if I rapidly removed the `NSTextField` item from the `NSToolbar` using `removeItemAtIndex:` and `insertItemWithItemIdentifier: atIndex:`, that would fool the OS into updating the `NSTextField` during a live window resize -- MOST of the time. However, the timer in the `NSTextField` still wouldn't update when you had dragged the window edge to resize it but were currently holding the mouse down with the pointer still -- i.e., you were still (cont.)

Comment: (2/3) ... in "live resize" mode because you hadn't let up on the mouse button, but not actively resizing either because the mouse pointer wasn't moving. In that case, the toolbar won't update even when you remove and add back items. So my fix for THAT was to detect when that case was occurring, and in addition to the first kludge, I used my `NSWindow`'s `setFrame: display:` method to quickly shrink the window's size by 1 pixel and then restore the size again. Unfortunately, this happens slow enough to see with the naked eye so it gives the window a very mild 'pulsating' look. I tried (cont.)

Comment: (3/3) ...fixing the pulsation by shrinking the window by only like half a pixel, but unfortunately that did not fool it into updating the toolbar -- it has to be a visible (1+ pixels) change to the frame size. Anyway, I guess it's close enough -- people don't usually resize windows and then keep the mouse button held down, and even if they do, they probably wouldn't notice the slight pulsation unless they were really paying attention. Still annoying that I can't find a perfect solution, though. Anyway, thanks for all help and if anyone has a better solution, I'd still love to hear it...

Comment: You might want to leave that as an answer to your own question (unless you can't) or edit it in your own question, it gets a bit long but glad you got a solution!

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer Thanks, yeah, I'd post it as a proper solution but I don't have enough reputation yet. If enough people see this and vote it up, I'll convert it to a solution when I have enough points to do so. I put a little note to that effect in the original question for now...

Answer (score 1):

Just invoke `-[NSWindow displayIfNeeded]` after marking the view as needing display. I encountered this problem when implementing the Mac driver for [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) (an open-source project for running Windows software on OS X and other Unix-like OSes).
http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/winemac.drv/cocoa_window.m?v=wine-1.7.11#L1905

(That's LGPL code, so you want to consider before *copying* it. But you can learn implementation techniques from it without worry.)

Comment: If only one view is a problem, why not call `-[NSView displayIfNeeded]`?  (I realize that may not be appropriate in the Wine case.)

Comment: @JWWalker, sure that should be fine, although the effects would be similar, even in terms of efficiency. The `NSWindow` method will only display those parts of its view hierarchy that need it. And the `NSView` method will go up the hierarchy to find an opaque ancestor.